# Subdivide 2 edges bug

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I tried subdividing 2 edges in this mesh and for some reason it kind of deformed it like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

In the settings at the bottom right you have *Smoothness* set to 2. Setting that to 0 fixes the issue.